# How to make line chart with grids as shown in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, dataset

I am new to R

Let's say I have this dataset in R:

```
dataset <- data.frame(Name = c("Steven","Ben", "Tim", "Rebecca", "Rachel"),
                      Time = c(18, 6, 29, 11 ,13))
```

I need to transform this data into a line chart with grid (5 lines) and y-axis from 0 to 35.

I have tried the following

sample code:

```
   library(grid)
  library(gridBase)

  plot(dataset$Name,
  ylim = c(0,35), col = "black",
  xlab = "Student names", ylab = "Time(s)"
  grid()
```

I am not sure, how to to get the exact plot as shown.

And also R automatically outputs alphabetical order of Names in X-axis but I want exactly as shown below. How can I do that?

Thank you so much for your help

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 library(tidyverse)

  dataset %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = factor(Name, levels = c(
      "Steven", "Ben", "Tim", "Rebecca", "Rachel"
    )),
    y = Time,
    group = 1
  )) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Student Names", y = "Time(s)") +
  #coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,35)) + # scale limits from 0 to 35
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 35), # scale limits from 0 to 35
    breaks = seq(0, 35, 10), # adjusted for grid
    labels = seq(0, 35, 10), # adjusted for grid
    minor_breaks = seq(0,35,5) # grid line between major grids.
  ) + 
  theme( # theme customization for major and minor grid.
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",colour = "black"),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(linetype = "dashed", color = "black"),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(linetype = "dotted", color = "grey")
  )
```

**Edit**

Added Walker's suggestion and theme to meet your expectations.

**Edit2**

Added limit.

**Edit3**

Added grid control. It can be controlled breaks, minor breaks, and few customization in themes. Hope it helps.

**Output**

[image]

**Output2**

[image]

**Output3**

[image]

Comment: For ordering x-axis values, check [here](https://www.rpubs.com/dvdunne/reorder_ggplot_barchart_axis)

Comment: Looks good, but is there anyway I can only have Y-axis ranging from 0 to 35 and grid lines exactly 5 ?

Comment: @SpecialCircumstancesAgent I have updated my code. please see.

Comment: Thank you that worked, but is there anyway I can control the number of grid lines? for example I don't want 8, instead I only 4. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Although a bar graph would me more appropriate than a line graph for this data, Neel's ggplot code will do the trick. If you only want to use base R code like your attempt then `dataset$Name=factor(dataset$Name, levels=c("Steven","Ben", "Tim", "Rebecca", "Rachel"))` will make your name variable use the given order rather than alphabetical order when displaying results.